# Corresponding SOAP UI vs Spring-ws

Tags: soapui, ws-security, spring-ws

Soap UI has the following option "Use single certificate for signing"
[image]

what is the corresponding spring-ws config?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

did you try with the Sign attribute includeTimestamp set to false?

According to the documentation, it's use to prevent replay attacks. Use Single certificate to signing in SoapUI use quite the same methodology as a replay attacks.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/XWS-SecurityIntro4.html#wp565497